# inherited objects in c++ and loss of attributes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, derived-class

I have :

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    void addClass(int id, C class);
    C getClass(int id);

private:
    hash_map<int, C> map; //TEMPLATE
};
```

Let's say `C` is a parent class. Is there any way in the main method to use the method `addClass` with an object of class `B` and another object of class `D` that both derive from class `C`? When I do this, and try the method `getClass`, I notice I will not be able to use specific attributes from either class `B` or class `D`, only the attributes from their parent, class `C`, as if they were converted into their parent class.  I tried using templates, but it doesn't seem to work :.

EDIT : Just completely failed that question, I didn't mean to derive class A from C...

Comment: Don't describe code in text, post it.

Comment: Slicing, or something like that?

Comment: Why would you want to derive `A` from `C`, doesn't make sense for me in your context.

Comment: You can add pointers to A or B classes. You can't add objects. You should use virtual functions. other option is dynamic_cast from base class pointer to its sub, but it can failed

Answer (score 2):

> as if they were converted into their parent class

They *are* converted to their parent class. Your function `addClass` takes a parameter of type `C` by value (that you've called `class`, but if you want it to compile you need another name because `class` is a reserved word in C++ can cannot be used as the name of a parameter).

Passing by value means the parameter is a copy of the object you specify in the argument expression. This copy has type `C`, it doesn't know about `B` and `A`.

It's exactly as if you had written:

```
void func(int a) { std::cout << a << '\n';}
...
func(1.5);
```

This prints `1`, not `1.5`, because the parameter `a` is the result of converting the value `1.5` to type `int`.

In your example code, you can instead pass a parameter by reference (since `C` is a base class of `B`: `int` is not a base of `double` so that option isn't available for my code). That is to say give it type `C&` instead of `C`. This means the function doesn't take a copy, instead it refers to the object you specify as the argument.

You can still only make calls on that object that are part of the interface of class `C`, but it will at least be an instance of `B` or `A`. Without knowing why you want to use attributes from `B` or `A` I can't tell whether this will solve your problem or not, but it's a start.

On a second look at your code: I suppose `addClass` is going to copy its parameter into the container named `map`. Again, this is a copy, so the value in the container will be an object of type `C`, not of some derived type. It may be necessary to use `shared_ptr<C>` or `unique_ptr<C>` instead of `C` as the value type, and dynamically allocate objects, but again I can't say for sure.